# Factory driven by enum attributes

Tags: c#

I have a situation where a factory pattern seems appropriate like this:

```
 enum Food {      
  Cake,      
  Cookies,      
  Milk,
  CannedBeans
}

public static class FoodMetaDataFactory{    
    public static IFood GetMetaData(Food foodType){  //takes a food enum value as a parameter
       switch(foodType){
          case Food.Milk:
             return new MilkMetaData();
          case Food.CannedBeans:
             return new CannedBeansMetaData();
          case Food.Cookies:
             return new CookiesMetaData();
          case Food.Cake:
             return new CakeMetaData();
       }
    }    
}
```

However, I'd rather have **more declarative pattern like this**:

```
enum Food {
  [FoodMetaDataAttribute(typeof(CakeMetaData))]    
  Cake,
  [FoodMetaDataAttribute(typeof(CookiesMetaData))]   
  Cookies,
  [FoodMetaDataAttribute(typeof(MilkMetaData))]   
  Milk,
  [FoodMetaDataAttribute(typeof(CannedBeansMetaData))]   
  CannedBeans
}

public static class FoodMetaDataFactory{    
    public static IFood GetMetaData(Food foodType){  //takes a food enum value as a parameter
        //reflectively retrieve FoodMetaDataAttribute
        Type enumType = typeof(Food);
        var memInfo = enumType.GetMember(foodType.ToString());
        //assume one item returned
        var foodMetaDataAttributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FoodMetaDataAttribute),
false);
        // now access the property telling us the concrete type of the metadata class(this is the type passed in the attribute's declaration
        Type targetType = ((FoodMetaDataAttribute)foodMetaDataAttributes[0]).MetaDataProviderType;     

        //not done yet, now we need to reflectively instantiate targetType, something like this            
        ConstructorInfo ctor = targetType.GetConstructor(new[] { });
        //invoke the constructor, returning concrete instance such as CakeMetaData
        return ctor.Invoke(new object[] {}) as IFood;     
    }    
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class FoodMetaDataAttribute : Attribute
{      
   public FoodMetaDataAttribute(Type metaDataProviderType){
      MetaDataProviderType = metaDataProviderType;
   }
   public Type MetaDataProviderType { get; set; }
}
```

I like this because it is clear to anyone adding new values to the enum that they need a meta data class and declare it in the attribute.  This IMO is better than having to remember to modify the switch case in a factory.

It seemed simple at first until I started to think about the implementation of GetMetaData that has to reflectively retrieve the attribute, the typeof parameter, and then reflectively instantiate the MetaData class.  **I'm not experienced in creating attribute classes, so the primary driver of this question is a hope that maybe there's a simpler way to accomplish this with attributes.**  If attribute classes didn't have so many restrictions, such as on using generic types, I'd have this done in a way I liked with some compile time safety.

This proposed solution has **no compile time safety**.  You can pass in types to the attribute that don't implement IFood, which is the minimum requirement for MetaData classes such as MilkMetaData.  If attributes allowed generic type parameters I'd use that instead of `typeof` and could apply a `where T:IFood`

**Is there a better way to utilize attributes to accomplish this mapping from enum value to concrete class?**

Comment: this question needs a class diagram

Comment: Classical class diagrams describe inheritance relationships.  They don't even describe composition, nor do they describe, "this code calls upon this class"(that's the job of a Sequence diagram speaking in UML terms).  I'm not sure what would be revealed in a class diagram since there's no inheritance here.  **Can you pinpoint where you are confused and I'll try to improve the question?**

Comment: i dont understand what concrete classes are involved in this or what is instantiating what.  you say there's no inheritance here but polymorphism is probably a pretty straightforward solution to the problem.

Comment: You obviously have a lot of data and behavior attached to each Food kind. Why not make `Food` a class with a private constructor and create a public static property for each kind (e.g. Milk, Cake, etc.). Then they will have the "feel" of an enum but can have other properties/methods on them.

Comment: @RobertLevy THere is only one place the MetaData classes are instantiated, and that occurs in GetMetaData, see in bold "**reflectively instantiate a concrete class** from the Type parameter such as a CakeMetaData class".  I will update question to try and elaborate.

Comment: I am going to rewrite the question and focus on just the factory pattern.

Comment: This is giving me a code smell, if the specific enum values and meta-data are that tightly coupled, just refactor to classes.

Comment: Did any of the proposed answers helped? If so, please select an "accepted answer", or specify why the answers were not.

Comment: @GregB What I'm proposing is indeed a refactoring to decouple the declarations so that the factory is not hardcoded to a finite set and will automatically support future enums without a code change.

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do in these cases is create a dictionary of factories, e.g.:

```
private IDictionary<MyEnum, Func<IMyInterface>> Factories = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Func<IMyInterface>> {
    { MyEnum.MyValue, () => new MyType() },
    // etc.
}
```

Simple and easy to maintain, extend or validate. You can create instance by doing:

```
IMyInterface instance;
if(!Factories.TryGetValue(enumValue, out instance))
    throw new Exception(string.Format("No factory for enum value {0}", enumValue));
return instance;
```

Note that separating the enum from the actual instance should be a **good** thing (split implementation from data). Otherwise, I suggest you simply pass on the actual type to a generic method.

Comment: This is an excellent way to do this and is what I've been using in the last year rather than switch statements. It's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that there is not a completely different approach that would be better, but there is just couple things you can improve in your current code:

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` instead of getting the constructor:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) as IFood;
```

You can also consider some kind of cache, to avoid doing all the reflection-related work on every single call. You can either store a single instance of concrete `IFood` implementation for each enum value, using simple dictionary:

```
public static class FoodMetaDataFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<Food, IFood> _cache = new Dictionary<Food, IFood>();

    public static IFood GetMetaData(Food foodType)
    {  //takes a food enum value as a parameter
        IFood value;
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(foodType, out value))
        {
            lock (_cache)
            {
                if (!_cache.TryGetValue(foodType, out value))
                {
                    var enumType = typeof(Food);
                    var memberInfo = enumType.GetMember(foodType.ToString());
                    var foodMetaDataAttributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FoodMetaDataAttribute), false);

                    var targetType = ((FoodMetaDataAttribute)foodMetaDataAttributes[0]).MetaDataProviderType;

                    value = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) as IFood;
                    _cache.Add(foodType, value);
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

or if you need each call to return fresh instance instead of shared one, you can use Expression Trees, to generate a `Func<IFood>` lambda expression when `GetMetaData` is called for the first time for given `enum` value, and call it later instead of reflection-processing.

**About compile-time safety:** I'm afraid you'd have to write your own custom check about that, e.g. as FxCop custom rule, or maybe something using Roslyn, if you're using newest (beta) version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

New here. To start from the end, If you want to use these Enum values for display, the best way to do it is to decorate them with an attribute that is a display string (or CSV), but if the values need to be complex, you should be using a Factory Method that creates new Food types. A base class can contain common values while each successive Child class has specifics that can then always be fed to the UI mechanism.

This only works if either each type creates it's own View or the views are common between types. This is similar to dependency injection in the second idea.

But if you want to add additional enums that represent code paths, you have to ALWAYS update your Controller\ViewModel unless there is some generic model that is always used for display.

I don't know your code base, so I don't know what type of refactoring would be required for a Factory or Adapter pattern.